# How to import only one part of a module and stop compiling other parts in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 files in my project.

**file1.py**

```
class A():
    # Some code...

class B():
    # Calling an API to get the data
```

Another file is:

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import A
# Some code....
```

The problem here is that I only want to import class A, but due to python default behavior it does compile the code written inside class B as well, which is calling an API unnecessary.

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you certain that class `B` is using the API *at import time*? That'd mean the API is being used *in the class body*, not in any of the methods.

Comment: @Amadan I could have split it, but what if I have multiple classes like this. In that case it wouldn't be good to have so many files.

Comment: @Amadan Anyway for my case I will split the file1.py.

Answer (score 2):

Just split out that code into separate modules, or refactor class `B` to not call an API on import.

Partial imports are not supported out of the box in Python; the only option the `import` mechanism gives you is loading the *whole* file **only**.

This means you'd have to do your own text file loading, then parse out the parts you want, then compile and execute those parts. This is fraught with problems, because you'd have to detect any dependencies yourself to make an informed decision as to what can and can not be omitted.

If you really want to go this path, you'll want to look at the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) to produce a tree of the objects contained in a module file. I'd use the line numbers on the objects to determine what parts of the original source file to compile (converting the tree back to bytecode is harder).

Comment: Thanks!, I think it is better to split out the code. I am a fan of you on this forum, and most of the times refers your solutions in python.